# Where is the order of parameters (naming of them?) in a pytest function documented?

Tags: python, parameters, pytest, fixtures

This seems like a very basic question, but I looked at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html, which I think is the reference for pytest and couldn't find the answer.

So I wanted to combine a `pytest.fixture` (setup/teardown using `yield`) with a `pytest.mark.parametrize` ... and I realised that they both have to be included as parameters in the test function.

A simple experiment showed that it doesn't appear to matter what order they are listed in the list of parameters, so my working assumption currently is that it never matters, and that, also, there are no (optional) named parameters in these methods.

It'd be nice to know if this is actually documented somewhere, and if I've got this right.

Comment: I would look around the [fixture documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#requesting-fixtures) for this. Basically, fixtures and fixture parameters are always looked up by name, so they can be in any order, and argument order only matters if the order the fixtures are executed matters, which will rarely be the case.

Comment: Thanks again. All clear now, hopefully. So all parameters of a pytest test are fixtures, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I put it in an answer to add the `patch` caveat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not explicitly stated, as far as I can see, but follows implicitly from the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#requesting-fixtures):

> When pytest goes to run a test, it looks at the parameters in that test function’s signature, and then searches for fixtures that have the same names as those parameters. Once pytest finds them, it runs those fixtures, captures what they returned (if anything), and passes those objects into the test function as arguments.

(*side note:* I generally recommend to check this documentation - it has been reworked recently and is very comprehensive IMO)

Fixtures are always looked up by name, so the order they appear in the argument list should not matter in principle.
This is also true for the arguments given in `pytest.mark.parametrize`, as observed.

Generally, the execution order of independent fixtures shall not matter, and if it does, it is either a bug, or the fixtures are not compatible.

There is one caveat: if you use fixtures together with positional parameters introduced by the `unittest.mock.patch` or `unittest.mock.patch.object` decorators (which are supported by `pytest`), the fixture arguments shall always be passed last:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("module.class")
def test_correct(mocked_class, capsys):
   ...

@patch("module.class")
def test_incorrect(capsys, mocked_class):
   ...
# fails because "mocked_class" is seen as an unknown fixture
```

This is not surprising, given how positional arguments work.
A way to avoid this is to use `pytest-mock`, which provides the `mocker` fixture:

```py
def test_correct(mocker, capsys):
   mocked_class = mocker.patch("module.class")
   ...

def test_correct2(capsys, mocker):
   mocked_class = mocker.patch("module.class")
   ...
```